# finding shortest path of all nodes from a given node using BFS

Tags: algorithm, c++11, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

when i increase or decrease INF value the Output Behaves Unexpectedly..
 I think INF should not have any effect on the output..
    length of each edge is 6
    for input
      1
      4 2
      1 2
      1 3
      1
   the output is 6 6 -1
      when I change INF to 1e8 the output is 0 0 0

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<vector>
 #include<queue>
 #include<cstring>

 using namespace std;

 #define MAX 2000
  #define INF 1000000

 vector<int> adj[MAX];
 int d[MAX];
  bool visited[MAX];

 void initialise(){
   for(int i=0;i<=MAX;i++){
  visited[i]=false;
   }
  }

  void shortestPathBfs(int start){

  queue<int> q;
   q.push(start);
     visited[start]=true;
     d[start]=0;

  while(!q.empty()){
      int p=q.front();
       q.pop();
      for(int i=0;i<adj[p].size();i++){
           int v=adj[p][i];
            if(!visited[v] && d[v]>d[p]+6){
                d[v]=d[p]+6;
                q.push(v);
               visited[v]=true;
            }
        }
       }
      }

         int main(){
         int T,N,M,S,x,y;
            cin>>T;
          while(T--){
        cin>>N>>M;
      for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
         cin>>x>>y;
          adj[x].push_back(y);
          adj[y].push_back(x);
      }
      cin>>S;

       initialise();
         memset(d,INF,sizeof(d));
         shortestPathBfs(S);

   for(int i = 1; i <=N; i++) {
        if(i == S)
            continue;
        if(d[i] >= INF)
              cout<<"-1"<<" ";
        else
            cout<<d[i]<<" ";
          }
       }

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with

```
memset(d,INF,sizeof(d));
```

`memset()` only fills memory with a *byte* value.  Here it will wind up filling the array with the least significant byte of the `int` value `INF`.  To fix it, create an explicit `for` loop or use [`std::fill()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) instead.

Comment: Also: the constant 6 in the lines `if(!visited[v] && d[v]>d[p]+6){` and `d[v]=d[p]+6;` looks incredibly suspicious...

Comment: You're welcome!  BTW, if you found it helpful then please upvote and accept my answer :)

Comment: I don't have much reputation to upvote ur answer..when i'll have i'll do it..thnks..